# Return local time from unix timestamp with timezone identifier in php

Tags: php, datetime, timestamp

I have a dropdown box on a webpage that takes a timezone identifier as the value (however I can change it to save the GMT offset if that is a better choice). Currently a user would be saving something like "America/Denver" as his / her time zone.

I need to convert a unix timestamp into the user's local time for display in another portion of the page. What is the best way to accomplish this?

Would it be better to store the GMT offset in the database and use that for a time calculation? Can someone please point me in the right direction here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest approach would be to use [`DateTime`](http://php.net/DateTime) with:

```
$t = new DateTime();
$t->setTimestamp( $time=time() );
$t->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone("America/Denver"));
print $t->format(DateTime::RFC850);
```

The timezone can be changed at will to cause the format function to recalculate the local time.

Comment: That's just a format string, like in `date()`. You can use any of those predefined in http://de.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php or supply your own `->format("d.M.y H:i:s");`

Comment: So I tried to set up the way you outlined above and I got this error message

"Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct() [&lt;a href='datetime.--construct'&gt;datetime.--construct&lt;/a&gt;]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'America/New_York' for 'EDT/-4.0/DST'"

Comment: Interesting. Then construct it like `new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone("America/New_York"));` - It should be possible to override this later, and changing the timestamp alike. Or really try the procedural version and preface everything with `date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");`

Comment: would I be able to feed in a unix timestamp in place of "now" ?

Comment: No, only as second step. The init parameter must be a formatted time string.

Comment: so then I would have to use setTime with a unix timestamp to set the time differently? Once I have initiated the dateTime object, I want to set it to a specific date / time representation of a unix timestamp so I can display that timestamp in the local timezone...

Comment: Timestamps are globally identical. The ->format output changes after each ->setTimeZone. Object can be reused, ->setTimestamp or ->setTimeZone as often as necessary.

Comment: Also, why is it considered not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings?

Comment: Weird, well I am getting closer with this. Just have to disable php warnings.

Comment: I got it! It all works beautifully! Thanks for all your help!!