# Perl: How to convert a unix timestamp+timezone into local time

Tags: perl, date, time, timezone, localtime

the basic question is in the header: I have a unix timestamp and a timezone, e.g. "America/Caracas" and I would like to convert it to the timezone's local time.

Searching through stackoverflow, I found someone else [asking pretty much the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397775/return-local-time-from-unix-timestamp-with-timezone-identifier-in-php), however, the provided answer code

```
$t = new DateTime();
$t->setTimestamp( $time=time() );
$t->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone("America/Denver"));
print $t->format(DateTime::RFC850);
```

does not work (anymore?). DateTime() does not allow me to set a timestamp; i did look through the DateTime source, but also did not see, where i could hook up my own timestamp. Any thoughts/help?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: That post refers to `DateTime in PHP` and not `perl`

Comment: ouch, i am completely overworked! thanks for that! woops!

Answer (score 4):

```
use DateTime;

my $dt = DateTime->from_epoch(
    epoch     => time(), 
    time_zone => "America/Denver"
);
print "$dt\n";
```

See the [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime) docs for details.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
my $epoch = time;
warn $epoch;
my $dt = DateTime->from_epoch( epoch => $epoch );
warn $dt->year;
#and so on
```

Comment: That does not work for me, i get an error when trying $dt-> year. Going through $ENV{TZ} works as a preliminary solution, though I read some posts that also do not recommend that.

Comment: Your code will return the UTC time, not the local time. That's probably what he meant with "does not work".