# Unix DateTime Discrepancy

Tags: c#, datetime, unix-timestamp

The function below is supposed to convert the following unix time into a C# DateTime object:

1362506086000

The time above is supposed to represent **March 5, 2012 12:54 PM**.

However, everytime I run it through the function below, it changes to **5:54 PM**:

3/5/2013 5:54:46 PM

```
    static readonly DateTime UnixEpoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    static readonly double MaxUnixSeconds = (DateTime.MaxValue - UnixEpoch).TotalSeconds;

    public static DateTime UnixTimeStampToDateTime(double unixTimeStamp)
    {
        return unixTimeStamp > MaxUnixSeconds
           ? UnixEpoch.AddMilliseconds(unixTimeStamp)
           : UnixEpoch.AddSeconds(unixTimeStamp);
    }
```

How can I get the unix time to be properly represented as **12:54 instead of 5:54**?

Comment: You probably need to look up the functions for converting GMT (or is it UTC these days?) into local time.  Perhaps this will help:  <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397775/return-local-time-from-unix-timestamp-with-timezone-identifier-in-php>  The language may be different, but the functions needed often have the same or very similar names across languages.

Comment: Good question; I don't know what timezone they are sending me.  I just know it is supposed to be 12:54 and when I plug it in my function it comes out 5:45...

Comment: @user1477388: You should ALWAYS ask yourself what timezone a date or time is in, BEFORE doing anything with it.

Comment: It's hard to know what timezone they are sending me; I would have to know where there servers are, correct?

Comment: If someone is sending you a datetime without a timezone, and you have no idea who they are or where they are located, then you don't really know at all what time they meant, do you.  You either need to agree on UTC, or send time in ISO8601 format with an explicit offset.  That goes into a `DateTimeOffset` in c#, and you can use the `o` format string for `ToString()` and `Parse()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix, for me, was to add `ToLocalTime()` to the code, like so:

```
static readonly DateTime UnixEpoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
static readonly double MaxUnixSeconds = (DateTime.MaxValue - UnixEpoch).TotalSeconds;

public static DateTime UnixTimeStampToDateTime(double unixTimeStamp)
{
    return unixTimeStamp > MaxUnixSeconds
       ? UnixEpoch.AddMilliseconds(unixTimeStamp).ToLocalTime()
       : UnixEpoch.AddSeconds(unixTimeStamp).ToLocalTime();
}
```

Comment: Careful there - `ToLocalTime()` might get a value that makes sense for you right now - but unless you can guarantee that the time stamp originated in the same time zone or is in UTC, then this will get you into trouble.  However - unix timestamps are *supposed* to be in UTC.  Just make sure that local time is really what you are after.

Comment: Thanks, Matt; I will consider that.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like a timezone issue.  Ensure that the timezone used to generate the Unix time is the same as the timezone on the Windows system, or convert accordingly.